# Can not get Resharper Test Runner working with MS Test on VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, resharper, mstest

I have recently upgraded to VS2010 Premium and Resharper 5.1.3000.12.  Its test runner will now not execute MS Tests.

The dialog shows up but nothing happens.

So when opening \Bin\Debug\TestResults .trx file, I see a list of tests reported as not executed.

They will execute fine if I click run from this dialog.

If I click to view the 'Test run error' link I see the error message:

> "Failed to queue test run
>   'user@network date': The system can
>   not find the file specified"

Nunit tests work fine.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, look like Resharper 6 does not have the issue.

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6.0+Nightly+Builds

I am using build #2150 on 09 May 2011, and now the tests run as expected.

Comment: I ran into the same issue with 5.1.3.  I upgraded to Resharper 6 RC to resolve the issue.

Comment: The root cause is that Microsoft modified Visual Studio 2010 MSTest assemblies which broke ReSharper 5.1.3. There is no way to fix ReSharper 5.1.3, so an update to 6.0 and above is required.

Answer (score 1):

By default resharper is configured to use shallow-copy assemblies being tested.

What you need to do is go to Resharper -> Options

From left side pane select tools  -> Unit Test

Uncheck Shallow-copy assemblies being tested

Then try running, Thats working for me.