# Dll Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CommandLine.dll version 10.0.0.0 is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, mstest

I try to run MsTest unit tests in Visual Studio 2010 with Resharper, but it says dll "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CommandLine.dll" version 10.0.0.0 not found. 
May be anybody know how to fix it or where I could find this dll or download it?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not get Resharper Test Runner working with MS Test on VS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944111/can-not-get-resharper-test-runner-working-with-ms-test-on-vs-2010)

Answer (score 0):

You must upgrade to a newer release of ReSharper (6.0 and above). There is no way to fix 5.1.3.

In Visual Studio 2010, that assembly is already installed to .NET GAC, and it is successfully resolved by ReSharper. The failure of running MSTest unit tests was caused by something else.