# Resharper can not debug my test case

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, resharper, mstest

I am trying to debug my test case using resharper Unit test session 
but i am not able to set break point at code

```
Error : The following break point can not be set 
Line no.xx Character yy
The common language runtime was unable to set breakpoint
```

Version Details: 
Resharper 8.01.14.856
Visual studio 2012 update 4

What I have tried

1. Upgraded resharper installation ( V. 8.2.1)
2. New installation of VS 2012

I have also searched similar question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944111/can-not-get-resharper-test-runner-working-with-ms-test-on-vs-2010),[this](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html) and many other question but no where i am getting solution 

Some facts

1. Same configuration on my team mates machine working fine, I also exported his VS setting and imported it on my machine still its not working
2. Resharper creates some folders under my project named testresult which contains my project dll's

Comment: @MichalHosala Sorry, It is VS 2012.

Comment: Thx for the clarification, so let me get this straight, when does the error happens? You just try to insert a breakpoint via Visual Studio and the error occurs? Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19005720/3242721)?

Comment: Yes, when i tried to set breakpoint via VS error occurred.

Comment: So then you perhaps want to review the SO thread I linked in previous comment. Either delete .suo file or repair your VS2012 installation, see if it helps.